# Order total discount in ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I want to total order discount in ubercart on drupal 7. I want to 10% discount on total order.Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What did you try to do so far? Where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[Commerce Discount Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra)

> Provides a number of common discount condition and offer types:
>
> **Order discounts**
>
> **Condition types**
>
> - Order-owner role
> - Total items in order
>
> **Offer types**
>
> - Fixed amount per-quantity discount (Buy X product get Y (or X)    product at discount up to some number of (or unlimited) times)
> - Percent per-quantity discount

[Ubercart Discount Coupons](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_coupon)

> A checkout pane, a cart pane and a block are available for customers
>   to enter coupon codes, each of which can be enabled or disabled
>   separately. Discounts can be shown as an item in the cart or applied
>   on the checkout page.